# retrieve multiple display information using win32/C++

Tags: c++, winapi, multiple-monitors, monitors

Is there any way to retrieve information about how many extra displays there are besides the main one, how they are numbered, what the dimensions are, etc?   I know this is pretty easy in .net land.

Comment: The link for "Number of physical monitors attached to a Windows machine?" above is broken.

Comment: This question should probably be marked as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022612/enumerating-monitors-on-a-computer. The current duplicate has been deleted after it was migrated to [su].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[EnumDisplayMonitors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162610(VS.85).aspx) should get you started.

Answer (score 5):

Use the EnumDisplayMonitors() function, passing NULL for the first 2 arguments.  Your [callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145061%28VS.85%29.aspx) gets the monitors in numeric order with their virtual location, relative from the main monitor.  Negative positions are to the left and top of your main monitor.