# EnumDisplayMonitors() invisible pseudo monitors

Tags: c++, msdn

In the MSDN describes EnmuDisplayMonitors as "...The EnumDisplayMonitors function enumerates display monitors (including invisible pseudo-monitors associated with the mirroring drivers)...". What are invisible monitors and how would I be able to tell them apart from the physical ones?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022612/enumerating-monitors-on-a-computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183569(v=vs.85).aspx

the StateFlags contains the value DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER for such kind of invisible pseudo-monitors.

So I think that's the information you where looking for.